# Where does the equation $(v_1 - v_2)^2 = 2as$ come from?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

Here is my exercise:

> A car ($v_1=20\ \mathrm{m/s}$) approaches a bike ($v_2=5\ \mathrm{m/s}$), both driving at constant speeds, to a distance of $l=50\ \mathrm{m}$. At that distance, it begins to decelerate in a manner that is just manages not to hit the bike (it stops right before it would hit the bike). What is the acceleration (or deceleration) of the car?

I've gone as far as to draw the graph and see that (if we mark the distance travelled by the bike from the time the car starts to decelerate until it stops as $x$) $x=v_2t$, and the same distance as travelled by the car is $x= v_1t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$. But from here on, there's no way to get to the acceleration because you don't have the time.

Our professor then asked me to write
$$(v_1-v_2)^2 = 2as$$
and from here we get $\lvert a\rvert > 2.25\ \mathrm{ms^{-2}}$. Why is this so? I don't understand what he did there ... is there an equation to start with to get to this?

Comment: You've got an equation wrong.  It's not $(v_1-v_2)^2=2as$ but rather $v_1^2-v_2^2=2as$.

Comment: @garyp That sort of thing should be developed into, and posted as, an answer. In any case it's been addressed in [a comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281114/calculating-the-deceleration-without-sufficient-parameters#comment630920_281117).

Comment: This is the equation that our professor had written and it stands well from the reference frame of the biker that nasu has mentioned.

Comment: It's the same as writing v^2 = (v1−v2)^2 +  2as with v=0 m/s, and you get a = - 2,25 m/s, which is the correct answer, only our professor forget about the minus, which is why he had taken into acount /a/.

Comment: " (it stops right before it would hit the bike)"  The car doesn't stop; it slows to the speed of the bike.  Unless the question means "stops approaching the bike"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to consider a reference frame related to one of the two moving objects. For example, in the reference frame attached to the bike, you have a car approaching a stationary bike. When the car is 50 m away, it has 15m/s of speed and it starts to slow down. A single equation of motion will solve the problem.

Comment: Ohhh, obviously ... !! Gosh, thanks a lot for putting this off my chest! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assume constant acceleration, and as acceleration is dv/dt, you can integrate twice ( also using v=ds/dt) where s is the displacement, you will get two equations from which you may eliminate t and get the equation your professor used. Also it is v^2-u^2=2as, not (v-u) ^2=2as.

Comment: The (v-u)^2 is ok in this context. It refers to the relative speed of the two objects. You don't need any integrations o solve this problem.

Comment: I know that integration isn't required, but I was answering his question "how to get that equation". Also even if relative velocities are used the equation won't be that one, it would be (v-u)^2 -  15^2 = 2as.

Comment: Final (relative) velocity is zero. Check again your initial and final parameters.  The equation is correct as written in the OP.                                 The answer to "how to calculate acceleration" is not always "do an integral". It wasn't for this problem.

Comment: I understand both your points of view. It's good to see how you to solve the exercise with integration (which I don't know yet, but will go learn straight away), and nasu's solution is very straight forward and simple. So thanks to both of you!

Comment: Can I ask either of you here to write how to solve this using integration? As I've said, we only did differentiation thus far at school and some guidance would be very useful ...

Comment: Assume a as constant, then dv/dt =a, dv=adt, integrate both sides to get, v=u+at, where u is the initial velocity, then v=ds/dt, again integrate, to get s=ut+1/2at^2. Basically I've derived the kinematical equations. You'll understand it better when you're taught integrals

Answer (score 0):

You should probably work in the reference frame where the bike is at rest, and the car is initially at a constant speed

$$v_0=15 m/s$$

You say that you don't have the time but you get the time of the (non) impact $t_0$ from:

$$v(t)=0=v_0 -at \longrightarrow t_0=v_0/a$$

Then you plug it into the equation for the position which is:

$$x(t_0)= d = v_0 t_0 -\frac{1}{2}at_0^2\longrightarrow a=\frac{v_0^2}{2d}$$

which is what you professor was suggesting written in the rest frame of the bike.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and simple way of presenting the solution! :)

Comment: You are welcome! reference frames are definitely one thing to keep in mind when solving this kind of problems...

Answer (score 0):

Start with the equation velocity with acceleration in one dimension
$$
v(t)~=~V(0) + at.
$$
Use the average velocity to get the displacement $d~=~v_{ave}t$ with
$$
v~=~\frac{v(t)~+~v(0)}{2}
$$
to the get the time it takes to displace the particle a distance $d$ as
$$
t~=~\frac{2d}{v(t)~+~v(0)}.
$$
Now eliminate the time by substituting this into $at~=~V(t)~-~v(0)$ to get
with some algebra
$$
v^2(t)~-~v^2(0)~=~2da.
$$